# Force Google Chrome (Or Chromium) to Manually Save VSphere HTML5 Password?

Tags: linux, macos, google-chrome, browser, chromium

System Info: Running Chromium on various Linux workstations and often Google Chrome or Chromium on one of my work MacBook Pros. I'm only a Firefox user when Google isn't watching (that's a joke, they're always watching hence why I use Chromium mostly now).

Firefox offers to save passwords for VMWare VSphere, but Google Chrome and Chromium do not offer to save my credentials, only suggest a list of valid and sometimes random usernames.

Q: Is there a method of forcing Google Chrome / Chromium to save a password that still works on the latest version? Thx